# macos nginx configuration file deos not exists

Tags: nginx, homebrew, macos-sierra

I have install nginx to macOS Sierra with Homebrew

```
brew install nginx
```

I would like to change some configuration, but I could not find nginx.conf

I have already check following locations.

> /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
>     /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.10.3

Where is nginx.conf located in macOS Sierra?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the answer.

run the following command

```
nginx -V
```

it will list all configuration arguments. nginx.conf location is mentioned at --conf-path argument.

```
--conf-path:~/brew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Comment: on ventura 13.1 apple silicon it's actually: '/opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'